# Bluetooth Serial Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, ionic2, android-bluetooth

I am trying to build a simple bluetooth serial app to connect to my arduino. I am using ionic2 to make android app.right now, all I am trying to do is list all the availabe bluetooth devices. Below is my code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BluetoothSerial } from 'ionic-native';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

public working:string;
public var2: string ;

bluetoothSerial.isEnabled(
    function() {
        this.working= "Bluetooth is enabled";
    },
    function() {
        this.working="Bluetooth is *not* enabled";
    }
);

public lists = [];

bluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired(function(devices) {
    this.lists.push(devices);
}, function(){  this.var2 = 'could not find any bluetooth device';});

  constructor() {  }

}
```

Whenever I do ionic serve I do plenty of error, mainly because Bluetooth is not recognized (function implementation is missing). It also does not allow me to build app either.

Please help on this.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs

> `isEnabled()`
>
> Platforms: Android  iOS  Windows Phone
>
> Reports if bluetooth is enabled
>
> Returns: `Promise` returns a promise

Couple of things. You cannot call your method like that.
You should capitalize your `BluetoothSerial`
You should put it in a function

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BluetoothSerial } from 'ionic-native';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

public working:string;
public var2: string ;
public lists = [];

constructor(){
   this.getAlBluetoothDevices();
}

// put BluetoothSerial inside a function, can't be called different
getAllBluetoothDevices(){
    // async so keep everything in this method
    BluetoothSerial.isEnabled().then((data)=> {
        // not sure of returning value, probably a boolean
        console.log("dont know what it returns"+data);

        // returns all the available devices, not just the unpaired ones
        BluetoothSerial.list().then((allDevices) => {
            // set the list to returned value
            this.lists = allDevices;
            if(!this.lists.length > 0){
               this.var2 = "could not find any bluetooth devices";
            }
        });
    });
   }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you  so much  mate!!!  I highly appreciate your time and help. I will try your  given code and will return to you with  update.  Thanks

Comment: Sure, I haven't used tis library myself. Check out the ionic2 docs for them if you have some spare time :) https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/bluetooth-serial/

Comment: Hey mate, Your code worked pefectly by removing `this.getAlBluetoothDevices();` from constrcutor (), i dont know why it was problem. Also BS.list only list paired devices not unpaired one ( this is also mentioned in BS docs too ). But yh its worked mate... Next thing Im gonna try connecting to a arduino device and see if it works.

Comment: @AmritSohal great to hear. I haven't ever used it myself but the ionic docs looked like `.list()` returned all. My bad :)

Comment: @AmritSohal please, accept the answer or write a better one to close the question.

Comment: Hello mate, I didn't close because  the Bluetoothserial.discoverUnpaired command still  not working...  Does not  matter  if you use .list or .discoverunpaired it only shows you list of paired  devices...  Sorry

Comment: Ah weird, you should consider submitting it as an issue on their github.

Comment: Thanks  geez. I will do so. Cheers

Comment: sorry I forgot to ask why I cannot use  this BluetoothSerial.isEnabled(success, failure); syntax, even though it is given this way in plugin github repository. Thanks

Comment: The `(data)` is basically your succes callback, instead of calling `function(data)`. *(TypeScript shizzle).* After this `data => {..}` you can define an error callback f.e. `.then(data => { ... }, error => { ... });`

Comment: Nice thanks !! But this process is complicated  when it has alot  after dot methods.. Subscribe .add .unsubscribe.. Etc

Comment: What do you mean by 'This process is completice'?

Comment: Sorry Im being  difficult  coz I don't  have any IT background..  Im just  making  an app to  control  arduino  and add some functionality  into  it.. I spent  alot timr searching for tutorials but cudnt find any based on latest ionic 2

Comment: Haha don't worry about your IT background, we're all here to learn. I just didn't understand what the sentence meant. Complicated or complete?

Comment: Ah yes in the beginning it can be a little hard to understand or feel very complicated, but once you start understanding what the methods actually do it will feel natural :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130268/discussion-between-amrit-sohal-and-ivaro18).

Comment: Hi, @Ivaro18 in this code : `Write (msg){

   BluetoothSerial.write(msg).then( res =>{
      this.status = ' This has been written :';
   }).catch(res=> function(){
     this.status = ' This has not been written :';
   }); `     any idea why succuss of failure callback in not being excuted?

Answer (score 1):

The below code is for scanning the Bluetooth device

```
    startScanning(){
        this.isScanning =true;
          this.bluetoothSerial.isEnabled().then(()=>{
            this.bluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired().then((allDevices)=>{
                this.devices=allDevices;
                this.isScanning =false;
            });
        });
```

And this code is for connecting to the device

```
onDeviceReady(){
  let device = this.navParams.get('device');


        this.bluetoothSerial.connect(device.id).subscribe((data)=>{
            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: 'Bluetooth',
                subTitle: data,
                buttons: ['ok']
                });
                alert.present();
        },error=>{
            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: 'Bluetooth',
                subTitle: error,
                buttons: ['ok']
                });
                alert.present();
        });

  }
```

Note:  It's working for me